# ngb-accordion ngbHeader <input> element enter toggles the panel and create new Object of the List

Tags: angular, header, toggle, panel

I have ngb-accordion working fine until I put a text input element in the ngbPanelHeader,

When I type some value in the following  text input element inside ngbPanelHeader section, the ngb-panel collapse and another panel is created automatically and displayed next

```
                <ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="false" [activeIds]="activeRule" formArrayName="rules" 
                (panelChange)="beforeChange($event);" #myaccordion="ngbAccordion">
                  <ngb-panel draggable *ngFor="let x of rules.controls; let i = index" id="{{'rule-' + i}}" 
                  title="{{'Rule-' + i}}" [formGroupName]="i">
            
                  <ng-template ngbPanelHeader >
                      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

                        <button (click)="togglePanel('rule-'+i);$event.stopPropagation()" class="btn btn-link">Rule</button>

                        <div>
                          <input type="text" class="priorityInput" placeholder='priority' formControlName='rulePriority'
                          (keyup.enter)="onRulePriorityValueTouched($event,i)">

                          <button  type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary ml-2" 
                            (click)="editOrSaveRule(i)"><i [class]="rules.at(i).disabled ? 'fa fa-edit' : 'fa fa-save'"></i>
                          </button>
                          <button  type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary ml-2" (click)="deleteRule(i)">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </ng-template>

                    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                      //some content
                   </ng-template>
                              
                  </ngb-panel>
                </ngb-accordion>
```

I tried searching google and applied some workarounds but nothing works so far, As you see I have tried stop.eventPropagation() on my onRulePriorityValueTouched($event,i) method

But it seems it's not the cause, because when I remove the calling function still if I enter anything in the text box still it toggles the current panel and creates another next panel?

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?
I tried from these solutions too, but still no luck on my case,

Here are my component class and methods:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {

  rulesManagementForm: FormGroup;
  activeRule:any;



  @ViewChild('myaccordion') accordion: NgbAccordion;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeFormProperties();
    this.activeRule = 'rule-'+ 0;
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {

  }


  initializeFormProperties() {
    this.rulesManagementForm = this.fb.group({
      rules: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

 get rules() {
    return this.rulesManagementForm.get('rules') as FormArray;
  }

  addNewRule() {
    this.activeRule = 'rule-' + this.rules.length;
    this.rules.push(this.newRule());
  }

  newRuleCondition() {
    return this.fb.group({
      dataPath: ['', Validators.required],
      operator: ['', Validators.required],
      value: ['', Validators.required],
      logic: '',
    });
  }

  newRuleAction() {
    return this.fb.group({
      action: ['', Validators.required],
      actionDataPath: ['', Validators.required],
      actionValue: ['', Validators.required],
      actionLogic: ''
    });
  }

  newRule() {
    return this.fb.group({
      rulePriority: '',
      ruleConditions: new FormArray([this.newRuleCondition()]),
      ruleActions: new FormArray([this.newRuleAction()])
    });
  }

   editOrSaveRule(i){
    const specificRule = this.rules.at(i);
    if(specificRule.enabled){
      this.createExpression(i);
      specificRule.disable();
    }
    else{
      specificRule.enable();
    }
  }

  deleteRule(i){
   this.rules.removeAt(i); 
  }

  onRulePriorityValueTouched($event,i){

    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.rules.at(i).patchValue({rulePriority: $event.target.value});
    (this.rules.at(i) as FormGroup).get('rulePriority').disable();
    //tempoary workaround for ngbaccordian header event triggering issue
    // this.rules.removeAt(this.rules.length-1);
    // this.accordion.toggle('rule-'+i);

  }

  togglePanel(id){
    this.accordion.toggle(id);
  }
  
  beforeChange($event: NgbPanelChangeEvent) {
    console.log("Panel Change: ",$event);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solutions on this but no luck, https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/717

Comment: Please find the working code with reproduce of the issue, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jf8zjr

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I was able to find the solution for this issue,

First i decided to migrate to ngb-accordian to mat-expansion-panel as a workaround but unfortunately even in mat-expansion-panel i faced the same issue, so i dig deep on default event triggering of expansion-panel and found out that,

They trigger expansion and collapse based on "keydow.enter" event, so changing my event detection to,

```
(keydown.enter)="onRulePriorityValueTouched(($event,i)"
```

solved the problem, this works for both ngb-accordion and mat-expansion-panel